# How do you implement specific behavior for a Mockery function

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I'm using the Go Mockery package, and I want the function `Next` to do some actions before returning. However, when I do this:

```
mockIter.On("Next", mock.AnythingOfType("*types.Query")).Return(func(q *types.Query) bool {
    condition := (do something that returns a boolean)
    return condition
})
```

I get this error:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is func(*types.Query) bool, not bool
```

I must be using the package wrong, but it seems like this is correct because they have this very similar example in their docs:

```
Mock.On("passthrough", mock.AnythingOfType("context.Context"), mock.AnythingOfType("string")).Return(func(ctx context.Context, s string) string {
    return s
})
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Return` function is used to return values on call of the mocked function. You can't change the signature of the mocked function.

Here you're returning `func(*types.Query) bool` (function that returns boolean) instead of `bool`, as the error message say.

You can have the function to make some computation and then return the value. You just have to add `()` (or whatever arguments your function accepts) after function definition to invoke it and you'll be good to go.

This works:

```golang
mockIter.On("Next", mock.AnythingOfType("*types.Query")).Return(func() bool {
    condition := (do something that returns a boolean)
    return condition
}())
```

But it seems to me that you want to do some computation based on the argument that is passed on the mocked call. I don't think mockery supports that at the moment.